# How should I efficiently update a Swing GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I created a program with a Swing GUI in NetBeans a while back using the Graphical Editor. I now needed a web version but since I use eclipse now I copied + pasted the code into a new Web Applet project. I found some problems I didn't spot before and updated the code in the web applet.

I want to add some buttons to the GUI, but one problem is its an annoyance to find the part of the code where NetBeans put all the variable declarations, then find another part of the code where all the fields are initialised, then find the other part of the code where the layout needs to be defined, then find the other part of the code where all the action listeners are added, etc... Another problem is that the Swing layouts are complex and also an annoyance to hard code... it is difficult to judge what the exact outcome will look like when you have to edit GroupLayouts with other swing components already layed out in them.

Also, I can't edit this in NetBeans because the Generator is very fussy and if I copy+paste code in there it wont read it as a Java Form nor generate an XML file which I think it uses to manage your layout.

Are there any free GUI designers out there that take a bunch of java swing code and allow you to graphically edit it? How do professionals manage their graphical layouts?

Comment: This is one of the main down-sides to creating a GUI using a gui code-generator, and this wouldn't be a problem if the GUI were written in a modular fashion with good MVC architecture and use of flexible layouts (not "hard-coded"). Consider just re-writing it.

Comment: How do you get around that in Netbeans? Or is the solution to not use Netbeans? Because in netbeans, you drag swing components onto a JFrame, right-click to add an action listener, and it automatically generates code which is un-editable (the field declarations are at the bottom, the layout code above that, and the initialisation of fields above that).

Comment: You would do it in NetBeans by using NetBeans as an IDE only, and not use its drag-and-drop functionality. Instead simply create your Swing applications in code and by hand.  If you have a GUI "form" created by a drag-and-drop code generator, and the form or its definition file somehow gets corrupted, you're toast.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have an image of your current GUI?

Comment: Theres not much code and I don't mind rewriting it. But wouldn't it take even longer to develop a Swing GUI by hand? The problem I have with Swing is that the layouts are fiddly (having to define a separate horizontal layout and a separate vertical layout) and I thought its much better a generator handle that for you. The only logic this particular GUI in question has is the button actions. Theres about 34% logic and 66% generated GUI. I know its better to separate logic from GUI completely and I much prefer the android enviroment for exactly that but how can I do that with Java SE?

Comment: I agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels. It's nice to save time for the creation of a GUI with a GUI Visual Editor, like the NetBeans's graphical editor, but, unfortunately there is no way to export the project with an IDE and load/continue to write it on another IDE. It's better to create by hand the GUI, according to me, to avoid these problems, to get experience, and to learn how code works, instead of using GUI code generator. For this reason, I can only advise you to re-write the GUI.

Comment: The layouts are not "fiddly" if you get very familiar with them and use them to best advantage. The more familiar you are with using them, the quicker and easier they are to use.  Regarding your question -- I'm not sure what you're asking, but if it's how to separate the logic from the GUI, there are several ways of doing this, everything from having inner anonymous listeners call a Controller's methods to using one or several design patterns such as the visitor pattern.

Comment: here is the screenshot you requested: http://tinypic.com/r/2bxk3r/5.
btw the code is actually in Eclipse now, but I didn't bother reorganising the code which I probably should do now. What I was trying to get at is if there is better software out there which forces you to separate code from GUI like you do with Android (XML files for layout only and java classes for code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I should have implemented the Model-View approach from the start.

Here is a nice tutorial on the subject:
http://people.csail.mit.edu/phw/OnToJava/ONTOJAVA755.HTML

Comment: nice link, I've been searching for something like this after spending many hours crying at NetBeans trying to understand how it 'puts together' all those gui elements. I'll give you a plus 1 when I've worked through the tutorial ;)